# Exception when calling da.Fill(dt)

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataadapter

I'm trying to display the name of products in a database, but it crashes on the line `da.Fill(dt)`

```
Cb_Produits.Items.Clear()
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand()
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "Select * From [Transaction]"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
DataTable dt = new DataTable()
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter()
da.Fill(dt)
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    Cb_Produits.Items.Add(dr["Nom_Produit"].ToString())
con.Close()
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: What's your question? What is happening that shouldn't? What isn't happening that should?

Comment: I would like to display my products from the base from the comboBox. When executing, it crashes at da.Fill (dt); While displaying the name of the Products stored in the database

Comment: With what exception? You really need to give us all the detail if you want help.

Comment: I would like to have access to the product names stored in the database at ComboBox level

Comment: Filling ComboBox with the column SQL ProductName

Comment: I had to assign the SqlCommand object to SqlDataAdapter.
da.selectCommand=cmd;

Comment: Made an actual question using information from the comments

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass your SqlCommand to the SqlDataAdapter constructor ...

...

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

...

and you should pass your connection to the SqlCommand constructor.